# Why does accessing variables declared without `var` work without having to use `require` in other files?

Tags: node.js

Here's an example

```
$ cat main.js
App = {
  version : 1.1
};
require('./mymod.js');

$ cat mymod.js
console.log(App.version);

$ node main.js
1.1
```

Note how I declared `App` in main.js without `var`. This allowed me to access `App` from `mymod.js` without having to call `require`. If I declare `App` with a `var`, this won't work.

I want to understand why this happens? Is it the intended behaviour for node.js or a bug? Is this behavior consistent with ECMAScript or CommonJS standards?

This trick gives a powerful mechanism to circumvent the `require` module system of node.js. In every file define your objects and add them to the top level `App` namespace. Your code in other files will be automatically have access to those objects. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assign a variable without using var, it is automatically a global variable. That's just the way JavaScript works. If you put `'use strict';` (quotes required) at the top of your js file, this becomes an error instead.

Comment: Highly recommend using strict mode and/or a good linter when programming in NodeJS.

Comment: I highly recommend using both. They catch different things.

Answer (score 1):

All has to do with local scope vs global scope.

You can even do this (which is much neater):

app.js:

```
exports = {
  version : 1.1
};
```

---

main.js:

```
var App = require('./app.js');
console.log(App.version);
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a variable without a preceding `var` will place it into the global namespace which is visible to all of your JavaScript code.

While this may seem a useful feature, it is generally considered bad practice to "pollute" the global namespace and can lead to subtle, hard-to-locate bugs when two non-related files both rely upon or define variables with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJS environment there is a global scope referenced by 'global' , just like the way we have 'window' in browser environments. In effect every javascript host enviroments always start with creating a global object.

When require('main.js') is executed, there is this following function that is created and executed against the global scope 'global'.

```
(function(exports,...){
   //content of main.js
   App = {
     version : 1.1
  };
})(module.exports,..);
```

When the above function is executed and since there is no var declaration for App , a property with name 'App' is created on global object and assigned the value.This behavior is according to ECMA spec.

That is how the App gets into global scope and is accessible across all modules.

`require` has been introduced to standardize development of modules that can be ported and used.

Comment: you can't have `module.exports` as a function parameter.

Comment: you are right , my intention is to convey what get actually passed and is referred to by exports insided a node module. It is just exports but to add more semantic i did it. I've corrected it now